# Autofilter method with a dynamically created array not filtering

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I've created a dynamic array from an Excel table using the following code.

```
For Each rCell In rngVisible
    ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To i)
    myArray(i) = rCell
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print myArray(i - 1)
Next rCell
```

This is how I'm instantiating this `myArray` variable.

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
```

From debug printing I know the array contains the items I need; however, when use in the `AutoFilter` method, it doesn't filter properly another table I have in the same sheet. After reading various posts, it was recommended that I transpose my array, which you can see below as `Application.Transpose(myArray)`, but it's not working. I've even made my array start at the 0 index. But the following line fails to properly filter my table

```
EventsTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(myArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Below is how that table looks (there's nothing in there apparently). But all the filters are still selected. Such a weird result/behavior. Can someone please share some thoughts as to why this might be happening? Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

****Below you can see the entire macro****

```
Sub ApplyFilterToTable()
Dim nonretired As Variant
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim SystemsTable, EventsTable As ListObject
Dim rngData, rngVisible As Range

' Defining and Filtering SystemsTable
Set SystemsTable = Worksheets("AllSystems_Filtered").ListObjects("SystemsTable15")
nonretired = VBA.Array("Ready for Use", "Service Due", "Out of Service", "Pending Log Entry")
SystemsTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=nonretired, Operator:=xlFilterValues

' Prework for filter matching 'Events' table based on Systems Table
LastRow = SystemsTable.Range.Rows.Count
Set rngData = Worksheets("AllSystems_Filtered").Range("F1:F" & LastRow)

'Set the visible range
With rngData
    Set rngVisible = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

' Now loop through the visible range to get the actual values
For Each rCell In rngVisible
    ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To i)
    myArray(i) = rCell
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print myArray(i - 1)
Next rCell

' Convert
right_array = VBA.Array(myArray)

' Defining and Filtering corresponding 'Events' table
Set EventsTable = Worksheets("AllSystems_Filtered").ListObjects("EventsTable16")
EventsTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(myArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need that `Transpose` here.  There's no other filtering applied on the sheet other than the one you apply via code above?

Comment: I tried it without `Transpose` at first. I added Transpose as recommended by others. And there is no other filtering that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is that the full table - just two columns?  Are the system Id's stored as numeric values?  Maybe you could add a little more code for context.  What/where is `rngVisible` for example?

Comment: Yes I'll update with the entire macro. And no I have more than two columns in that table. I'm seeing that they are formatted as 'General'

Comment: Are the tables side-by-side on the sheet?  I notice you don't remove the filtering from `SystemsTable` before filtering `EventsTable`.

Comment: No one table is below another one

Comment: In that case I can't reproduce (but I don't have your exact data...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (one table above the other):

```vb
Sub ApplyFilterToTable()
    Dim nonretired As Variant
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, wsSystems As Worksheet
    Dim SystemsTable As ListObject, EventsTable As ListObject
    Dim rngVisible As Range, rCell As Range, dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set wsSystems = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AllSystems_Filtered")
    
    nonretired = VBA.Array("Ready for Use", "Service Due", "Out of Service", "Pending Log Entry")
    
    ' Defining and Filtering SystemsTable
    Set SystemsTable = wsSystems.ListObjects("SystemsTable15")
    UnFilter SystemsTable     'clear any previous filters
    SystemsTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=nonretired, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    'all visible cells in col#6 (or use the header name)
    On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if no visible rows
    Set rngVisible = SystemsTable.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rngVisible Is Nothing Then
        
        For Each rCell In rngVisible
            dict(CStr(rCell.Value)) = True 'collect unique values as keys in dictionary
        Next rCell

        Set EventsTable = wsSystems.ListObjects("EventsTable16")
        UnFilter EventsTable       'clear any previous filters
        EventsTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    End If
End Sub

Sub UnFilter(lo As ListObject)
    On Error Resume Next
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Never used this Dictionary object before

Comment: Will try to use this

Comment: I find it's a bit easier than building up an array using `Redim` (as long as you don't need to support Mac users).  Your array approach also worked fine for me though.  Note you can size the array in one step - `ReDim myArray(0 To rngVisible.Cells.Count - 1)` before you go into the `For Each rCell` loop.

Comment: ohh ok I see I also noticed you cleaned this part (which I didnt think to do before) `rngVisible = SystemsTable.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: If you're working with ListObjects there are some useful methods/properties that are worth exploring and can save a few lines of code here and there...

Comment: On the line Unfilter SystemsTable, I'm getting a compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: You need to declare a specific type for **each variable** if you don't want them as `Variant`...  `Dim SystemsTable As ListObject, EventsTable As ListObject`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246796/discussion-between-diego-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Thanks so much for the back and forth. I don't really know how, but this solved my problem.

Comment: OK - good to hear